# Adding Python functions to be called when motion is detected

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2, sensor

The below code is meant to call the camera and email functions when motion is detected. I tried adding the functions after printing Motion Detected but didn't work. Where to add these functions?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import socket
import datetime
#Camera
import os
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame.camera
#Email
import os
import smtplib
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
#Sensor
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

COMMASPACE = ', '
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PIR_PIN = 7
GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)

def MOTION(PIR_PIN):
      print(“Motion Detected!”)

print(“PIR Module Test (CTRL+C to exit)”)
time.sleep(2)
print(“Ready”)

try:
    GPIO.add_event_detect(PIR_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=MOTION)
    while 1:
           time.sleep(100)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print(“ Quit”)
     GPIO.cleanup()

def camera():
    width = 480
    height = 360

    #initialise pygame   
    pygame.init()
    pygame.camera.init()
    cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(width,height))
    cam.start()

    #setup window
    windowSurfaceObj = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),1,16)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Camera')

    #take a picture
    image = cam.get_image()
    cam.stop()

    #display the picture
    catSurfaceObj = image
    windowSurfaceObj.blit(catSurfaceObj,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()

    #save picture
    pygame.image.save(windowSurfaceObj,'picture.jpg')

def email():
    sender = ''
    gmail_password = ''
    recipients = ''
    composed = ''

    # Create the enclosing (outer) message
    outer = MIMEMultipart()
    outer['Subject'] = 'MOTION HAS BEEN DETECTED!'
    outer['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(recipients)
    outer['From'] = sender
    outer.preamble = 'You will not see this in a MIME-aware mail reader.\n'

    # List of attachments
    attachments = ['/home/pi/Desktop/picture.jpg']

    # Add the attachments to the message
    for file in attachments:
    try:
        with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
            msg = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
            msg.set_payload(fp.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(msg)
        msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(file)) 
        outer.attach(msg)
    except:
        print("Unable to open one of the attachments. Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise

    composed = outer.as_string()

    # Send the email
    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as s:
            s.ehlo()
            s.starttls()
            s.ehlo()
            s.login(sender, gmail_password)
            s.sendmail(sender, recipients, composed)
            s.close()
        print("Email sent!")
    except:
        print("Unable to send the email. Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise

MOTION(PIR_PIN)
```

Comment: The code as presented is syntactically incorrect.  E.g. there must be an indentation after def camera:  Could you post the correctly indented code?  It is important as the indentation changes the meaning of the script.

Comment: I changed the code with how it is indented. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code still contains syntax errors.  An unindented try after a for and the use of non-standard quotes such as “ rather than ".

You need to call functions.  You need to add a call to camera() and email() in your MOTION function.  I.e.

```py
def MOTION(PIR_PIN):
      print("Motion Detected!")
      camera()
      email()
```

Comment: i tried doing like your code but it says that camera is not defined even if i do the email only. Thanks

Comment: You have done something wrong.  I don't know what.

Comment: Solved changed the sensor code to the last part after the email code and worked. Thanks for the help!